# Excel File HyperLink is not bring me to the complete url

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I did a hyperlink in excel file,
this is the link 
http://10.112.96.130:8087/Canary/cmrt/evaluateCMRT/3184726

and when i clicked on the hyper link it bring me to 
http://10.112.96.130:8087/Canary

i already try to find why this is happening.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to replicate your error. Are you entering data into a cell, right-clicking on the cell, then 'Hyperlink' then making sure that you have 'Existing File or Web Page' selected before putting in your URL?

[image]